# UITest keeps failing to tap alert view when running on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcuitest, xctestcase

I have created a series of UI Tests that run fine on a device but when using a Simulator, I cannot tap alert view buttons.

```
 let alert = app.alerts["Continue"]
 alert.buttons["Yes"].tap()
```

Instead, it crashes with

```
Find: Descendants matching type Button
t =    10.17s     Find: Elements matching predicate '"Yes" IN identifiers'
t =    10.18s     Check for interrupting elements affecting "Yes" Button
t =    10.19s     Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 14120
t =    10.21s     Find: Descendants matching predicate identifier == "NotificationShortLookView" OR elementType == 7
*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil (NSInvalidArgumentException)
```

I believe (and hope) this is an Xcode 13 bug and may be fixed in an update soon.
Does any one know a way around this?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out this is only an issue when running on an iOS 12 simulator. It is ok when running on an iOS 15.4 simulator.

Comment: I'm using an iOS 15.4 simulator and I still get this error :(